# How can I let users log in to plone site with their facebook or google account cresidentials

Tags: python, facebook, plone

I am trying to login with facebook to my plone site. I have created APPID/APPkey and APPsecreat,Accesstoken in developer facebook apllication. I installed collective.portlet.embed package in buildout.cfg file. I got the facebook login logo in my plone site. The problem is i can't able to login with facebook. I am getting the below error

```
 "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given 
  URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, 
  or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."
```

I want to test locally whether can be able to login or not in facebook. My plone site http://**localhost**:8080/projectname. Anyone help me to solve this error and how to configure the settings for to rectify the above error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To login into a Plone site you need a [PAS plugin product](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=plone%20pas&submit=search), and `collective.portlet.embed` is not.

You have some choices:

- [plonesocial.auth.rpx](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plonesocial.auth.rpx) - relies on 3rd part service, but provide all OAuth authentications
- [cs.auth.facebook](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cs.auth.facebook) - easy to install, do not rely on RPX service as above, but only for Facebook
- [pas.plugins.velruse](http://plone.org/products/pas.plugins.velruse/) - it can cover all authentication providers like plonesocial.auth.rpx but is more complex to be installed

Keep in mind that you can still use Google authentication using it's OpenID support. Just activate the pre-installed Plone OpenId support.

PS: I think that testing Google authentication from localhost will not work. You must go live.

Comment: thanks.. i successfully logged in with facebook account... But one doubt we defined My APPID/APP secret in facebook settings in plone site... so we logged in easily but i want to know different user login in plone site... when different user trying to login means that am getting the below error "App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app properly for Facebook Login."

Comment: Meanwhile I expanded the response (I forgot the probably most important add-on: plonesocial.auth.rpx).
The error you are getting seems only related to the FB app configuration.

Comment: yes as u said i did everything in plone site and developer facebook. In this way me only can able to login with my facebook account. but others can't able to do.. if u have any idea about to change settings share with me.. thanks